# Divide quantity for per user

Tags: javascript

How to split by users to per 4 or remainder of total users?

Quantity value 4 is very good working but 5 not also has remainder...

How to apply without if blocks ? In twice loop.

```
var quantity = 5;
var limit = Math.ceil(quantity / 4)
var users = [...Array(limit).keys()];

for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++)
{
    if(i != users.length-1) // check is last
    {
        for(var r = 0; r < 4; r++)
        {
            console.log('index of user: ' +i + ' action index: ' + r);
        }
    } else { // of remainder (i no found solution in this block)

    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
index of user: 0 action index: 0
index of user: 0 action index: 1
index of user: 0 action index: 2
index of user: 0 action index: 3
index of user: 1 action index: 4 (only this not real on code)
```

Last edit:

How to apply if blocks in loop ? I think we make it in loop.

```
var quantity = 5; // max action
var limiter = 4; // per user action limit

var limit = Math.ceil(quantity/limiter);
var users = [...Array(limit).keys()];


users.forEach((user, i) => {
  for(let j=0; j<limiter; j++) {

    if(i*limiter + j >= quantity) // make it loop
        break;

    console.log(`index of user ${i} action index: ${i*limiter + j}`) 
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, could you please add some sample data and expected result for better understanding?

Comment: @elvira.genkel added.

Comment: Could you try to use Google Translate?  I'm having difficulty understanding your English and finding it challenging to ascertain what you are doing and what you want

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing this I think the best thing to do is store the actions number separately and then use the index to get multiples of it. I can't tell from what you've provided if the `4` in limit is related to number of actions but if it is you can simply substitute the variable in its place.

```js
var quantity = 5;
var limit = Math.ceil(quantity/4);
var users = [...Array(limit).keys()];

var actions = 4;

users.forEach((user, i) => {
  for(let j=0; j<actions; j++) {
    console.log(`index of user ${i} action index: ${i*actions + j}`) 
  }
});
```

Comment: users variables data coming from sql. also users real: 

```
var users = query("SELECT * FROM users LIMIT " + limit)
```

How to apply for this reason?

Comment: @latwe55 I'm guessing you want to use the actual index then, and not the user element in `users`. This can be done by replacing `user =>` with `(user, index) =>` and replacing all references to `user` with `index`.

Comment: You targeting quantity value. Also you getting more users. Per user have 4 action limiter.

Comment: Sorry, I think I've misunderstood what you're trying to do. I'll take another look but if you could try and provide more detail in the question that would be great.

Comment: In your original question `limit` equals `2` - are you saying you want to log four actions for two users, ranging from 0 to 7?

Comment: Yes limit  actual value equals to 2.  Per user for have max 4 action. You code with my old code is same. I now use "LIMIT" sql query for less data also have 4 action limit.

Comment: Action max must be equal to quantity value.

Comment: @lawrence-witt I edited question please look last edit. Thanks.